What is the maximum load in the puncture resistance formula?
I've been trying to research how fencing jackets work and I've learned about puncture resistance but I was trying to find the formula for how it was calculated and I found this website that gives me the formula
$$\text{Puncture Resistance} = \frac{\text{Maximum Load}}{\text{Material Thickness}}$$
but it doesn't actually say what "maximum load" means; one of my friends was thinking maybe tensile strength? Another suggested maybe it was the max weight a material could hold up but we're kinda just throwing out guesses cause I can't find anything about it online.

If I'd have to guess, I'd say its the maximum force that the tip of a sword can exert before it breaks through the material (or maybe there's some standardized puncture device used for testing).
